# Typescript method not visible (using site dev)

Tags: typescript, vite, lit

I have this Typescript code for my lit component:

```
  render () {
    const graph : GVGraph = this.graph
    const svgEle = graph.asSVG()
    return html`
       ${svgEle}
    `
  }
```

Everything works well in my IDE VS Code. Typescript transpiler doesn't complain. Vite does also do its magic. But at runtime Safari shows this error:

```
TypeError: graph.asSVG is not a function. (In 'graph.asSVG()', 'graph.asSVG' is undefined)
```

But the method is even in the sources of the browser... see here (see class/method):
[image]

So, how could that be? Why would the code fail at runtime? Any ideas? Where do I need to look?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `graph` at runtime?

Comment: Thanks! That's it. In spite of my type declaration, Javascript considers it a `string`.